# Do Lost kills give experience?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

Does killing The Lost in XCOM 2: War of the Chosen grant promotion experience?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are supposed to grant experience. The experience they grant is greatly reduced though.

Comment: Is it reduced the more you kill or... ?

Comment: Well, my rookies just gained a promotion after 2 Lost kills, they also only gained a single AP from high ground shots after 2 Lost kills (both kills made by the same soldier). Please amend this to your answer.

Comment: If I remember correctly the livestream before launch said something like 1/4th of the experience you normally get. I can't look into the code right now, so I can't give a definitive answer based on that.

Comment: I also tried to farm some AP and experience right now but I _think_ (and am not sure) the original Lost on the map grant experience but any new swarms that appear do not grant any XP or AP.